# How can i write this XAML with c# code?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

how can i write the following xaml with c# code?

```
 <DataGridTextColumn 
     Header="{Binding (FrameworkElement.DataContext).NamedRankTypeHelper.NamedRankTypeList,
                      RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                      Converter={StaticResource GridHeaderListeToHeaderValueConv},
                      ConverterParameter=1,
                      FallbackValue=Filter1}" IsReadOnly="true">
     <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
          <Binding Path="Programm" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
          </Binding>
     </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
  </DataGridTextColumn>
```

i tried this but my problem is the **(FrameworkElement.DataContext)**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= maxRank; i++)
        {
            this.GridDruckUndVersand.Columns.Insert(i + start,
                new DataGridTextColumn()
                {
//dont know how i can put in (FrameworkElement.DataContext)
                    Header = new Binding("(FrameworkElement.DataContext).NamedRankTypeHelper.NamedRankTypeList")
                                    {
                                        RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self),
                                        Converter = new NamedRankTypeToGridFilterHeaderConverter(),
                                        ConverterParameter = i.ToString(),
                                        FallbackValue = "Filter "+ i.ToString()
                                    },
                    IsReadOnly = true,
                    Binding = new Binding("FilterItems[" + i + "]")
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the () around the FrameworkElement.DataContext are doing, but you're missing the open one in the C# version.